# GLib-GObject-WARNING when closing gvim

Tags: vim, gvim, glib

I set my computer up new with Ubuntu 16.04 today. I already installed vim-gnome. While working with it, everything is fine. But when I close gvim I get this message in the terminal:

```
(gvim:5834): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot retrieve class for invalid (unclassed) type '<invalid>'
```

It is not making any problems, still I want to settle this problem, before it could effect something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem, got rid of it by removing `vim-gnome` and installing `vim-gtk` instead:

```
sudo apt-get remove vim-gnome
sudo apt-get install vim-gtk
```

Comment: I thought I tried that before, must have done a mistake. Now it is working fine!